# How to get LAC and/or CellID using Swift

Tags: ios, mobile, cellid

Dear friends of StackOverflow,
I found out how to get the MNC (**M**obile **N**etwork **C**ode) and MCC (**M**obile **C**ountry **C**ode) for an iOS device but I really need to get information about the CellID and the LAC (**L**ocation **A**rea **C**ode). It's not an app which is so supposed to get into the AppStore, we need this for internal testing.
I know, its possible to get MNC/MCC like that:

```
var mob = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()  

    if let r = mob.subscriberCellularProvider {  
        print("CountryCode: \(r.mobileCountryCode!)")  
        print("NetworkCode: \(r.mobileNetworkCode!)")  

    }
```

But are there any possibilities for getting LAC/CellID using swift in iOS 11?

Comment: I mean the Location Area Code, the Mobile Network Code and the Mobile Country Code.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code and I have added it

```
import UIKit
 import CoreTelephony

class mobile: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      let telephonyInfo: CTTelephonyNetworkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
      let carrierNetwork: String = telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology!
      print("mobile network : \(carrierNetwork)")

      let carrier = telephonyInfo.subscriberCellularProvider

      let countryCode = carrier?.mobileCountryCode
      print("country code:\(String(describing: countryCode))")

      let mobileNetworkName = carrier?.mobileNetworkCode
      print("mobile network name:\(String(describing: mobileNetworkName))")

      let carrierName = carrier?.carrierName
      print("carrierName is : \(String(describing: carrierName))")

      let isoCountrycode = carrier?.isoCountryCode
      print("iso country code: \(String(describing: isoCountrycode))")

  }



}
```